# Configuration for AWS RDS Aurora autoscaling to handle high concurrent traffic spikes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, scaling, amazon-aurora, auto

We have an application deployed on AWS.

The application runs on EC2 instances with Auto Scaling and Amazon Aurora also with Auto Scaling.

This app works as a middleware that receives and processes multiple requests from other services over HTTPS and most of the time the app works pretty well.

However, sometimes (at least 1 time a day) the application receives high simultaneous traffic spikes (more than 200 requests per second for about 1 minute) and this is when the problem arises.

EC2 instances can handle this traffic without much effort. The CPUs of the EC2 instances don't even reach the 40% threshold.

On the other hand, the Aurora autoscaling policy triggers the autoscaling process and creates new replicas. The thing is, by the time the new DB instances become available, the high concurrent traffic is over and most requests fail (timeouts).

So how can we deal with it? Is there a way to make the autoscaling process faster?

We tried various autoscaling policy configurations without success.

We expect the autoscaling process to be faster and handle the traffic on time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider switching to [Aurora Serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/). It's ideal for sudden workload spikes since it takes a lot less time for a serverless cluster to scale compared to creating a new replica. You can try [serverless v1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html) first, and if it still doesn't scale fast enough for your needs, then use [serverless v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.html), which scales faster than v1 (although it's also more expensive). See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aurora-migrate-provisioned-serverless/ for steps to migrate from provisioned to serverless.